# Adaptive Card Issue in Microsoft Teams Tabs with teams-js and Angular

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js, live-share

We are currently facing an issue with adaptive cards within our Microsoft Teams tabs. This has been functioning correctly since the launch of our application, but we've recently encountered a problem.

When we execute the following code:

```js
dialog.adaptiveCard.open(adaptiveCardDialogInfo, dialogResponse);
```

The application breaks.

Additionally, the method:

```js
dialog.adaptiveCard.isSupported() //is returning false.
```

Unfortunately, no explicit error message is displayed, but we do receive an
**errorCode: 100**.

Our current versions are:

```js
@microsoft/teams-js: 2.12.0
@angular/core: ^15.0.0
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue or can provide some guidance on how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample Code:

```js
      card: JSON.stringify({
        type: "AdaptiveCard",
        body: [
         {
          type: "TextBlock",
          size: "Medium",
          weight: "Bolder",
          text: "Select user(s) in your organization."
         },
         {
          label: "1) Select user(s): ",
          isRequired: true,
          placeholder: "Search and select user(s)",
          type: "Input.ChoiceSet",
          choices: [],
          "choices.data": {
            type: "Data.Query",
            dataset: "graph.microsoft.com/users"
          },
          id: "selection",
          isMultiSelect: true,
          errorMessage: "Atleast one user must be selected."
         },
         {
          isRequired: true,
          label: "2) Message",
          type: "Input.Text",
          size:"Medium",
          placeholder: "Enter your message",
          id: 'message',
          errorMessage: "A message is required."
         },
         {
          type: "Input.Toggle",
          label: "3) Summary",
          title: "Include Summary?",
          valueOn: "1",
          valueOff: "2",
          value: "1",
          id: "sum_type"
         }
        ],
        actions: [
          {
            type: "Action.Submit",
            title: "Cancel",
            associatedInputs: "none"
          },
         {
          type: "Action.Submit",
          title: "Send"
         },
        ],
        $schema: "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        version: "1.4"
       })
    }
    // RUN 
    dialog.adaptiveCard.open(adaptiveCardDialogInfo, dialogResponse);
```

Thank you!